# Red color in POST data in Request Body in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmx

In JMeter in View Result Tree in the section Request-Request Body I have a red colour text in the POST data. Is it ok?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp2mN.png)
Red colour I have also in Get data in Request Body
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcHCO.png)

I tried to do performance test with 50 users. The test was recorded by Blazemeter, and then I download it to JMeter. On 50 different users I made a variable from csv file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HD6a.png)
In the Thread Group I have 50 users, ramp-up period 60 sec, loop count 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore this safely, I think it's some form of [syntax highlighting](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61769) which is unnecessary and harmful.

In general you should not be using any Listeners for high-scale performance tests, you should be [running JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) with all listeners disabled. See [Reducing resource requirements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) user manual chapter for more details.

View Results Tree listener should be used for ensuring that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing with no more than 1-2 users/iterations.